# How to format numbers depending on current language with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, internationalization

Please correct me if I'm wrong but I think Laravel doesn't come with number *translator* feature.

```
Github > laravel/framework > Search string > "number_format"
```

Anyway, how can I format properly a number depending on the current language in Laravel?

It can be done with `number_format` according to [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), but I want a general way of doing it other than adding some conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be using the `NumberFormatter` class which comes with PHP.

```
$num = NumberFormatter::create('en_US', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
echo $num->format(10000000);
```

For different locales, just pass in a different locale to the constructor.